# JSON PHP output missing cols and rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, output

I want to output my php database to JSON.
It is working but i'm missing the cols and rows part in my json.

I want to use this for google charts.

first of all this is my user.php (in this file i want to show how many users registered in the last 7 days with help from the google charts function:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
include 'nav.php';
include 'sidebar.php';
?>


        <div class="row">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="admin.php"><svg class="glyph stroked home"><use xlink:href="#stroked-home"></use></svg></a></li>
                <li class="active">Registrations</li>
            </ol>
        </div><!--/.row-->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Registrations</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table data-toggle="table" data-show-export="true"  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true"data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="name" data-sort-order="desc">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Last name</th>
                  <th>Degree</th>
                  <th>Organization</th>
                  <th>Industry</th>
                  <th>Address-1</th>
                  <th>Address-2</th>
                  <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/> Select All</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                      $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID>1");
                      $table = array();
    $table['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'projid', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'string'),
    array('id' => "", 'label' => 'hours', 'pattern' => "", 'type' => 'number')
    );
                       $rows = array();

                       if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 1){
                      ?>
              <?php
                  // output data of each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                ?>


                <tr>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row['userID'] ?>      </td>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row["userName"] ?>      </td>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row["userLast"]  ?>        </td>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row["userDegree"]?>       </td>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row["userOrganization"] ?> </td>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row["userIndustry"]   ?>   </td>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row["userAddressone"]  ?> </td>
                  <td class="info-item">                        <?php echo $row["userAddresstwo"]  ?>   </td>
                  <td class="info-item" style="width: auto;">
                    <input class="allselect" name="checked_id[]" type="checkbox"  value="<?php echo $rows["userID"] ?> "/></td></td>
                <?php  } ?>
                <?php
                } else {
                  echo "<table>";
                  echo "<tbody>";
                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td class='info-item'>No Records found!</td>";
                  echo "</tbody>";
                  echo "</table> ";
                }?>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
                        </table>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-right: 0px !important;">

            </form>

            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.row-->

  <div id="chart_div"></div>

    </div><!--/.main-->

    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/chart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script>
        !function ($) {
            $(document).on("click","ul.nav li.parent > a > span.icon", function(){
                $(this).find('em:first').toggleClass("glyphicon-minus");
            });
            $(".sidebar span.icon").find('em:first').addClass("glyphicon-plus");
        }(window.jQuery);

        $(window).on('resize', function () {
          if ($(window).width() > 768) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('show')
        })
        $(window).on('resize', function () {
          if ($(window).width() <= 767) $('#sidebar-collapse').collapse('hide')
        })
    </script>
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

The chart_div is located in the user.php file at the bottom:

```
<div id="chart_div"></div>

    </div><!--/.main-->

    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/chart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/easypiechart-data.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
```

In my header.php file i have this code from google:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType: "json",
      async: true
      }).responseText;

  // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

  // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}

</script>
```

With this file i generate my JSON from my PHP database:

```
    <?php
    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","register") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));



    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));



    //create an array
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }



header('Content-Type: application/json');
    //write to json file
    $fp = fopen('users.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
    fclose($fp);




//close the db connection
   mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

This is my getData.php file:

```
<?php

// This is just an example of reading server side data and sending it to the client.
// It reads a json formatted text file and outputs it.

$string = file_get_contents("users.json");
echo $string;

// Instead you can query your database and parse into JSON etc etc

?>
```

But the problem is that is outputting this:

```
[{"userID":"1","userName":"admin","userLast":"admin","userDegree":"HBO","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"asd 1","userAddresstwo":"asd1","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"d33164cb6de8ee9471a34ece95d91abb"},{"userID":"22","userName":"a","userLast":"Bernard","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"a@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"23","userName":"b","userLast":"Jansen","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"b@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"24","userName":"c","userLast":"Vermeer","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"c@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"25","userName":"d","userLast":"van Vliet","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"d@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"26","userName":"e","userLast":"Petersen","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"e@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"27","userName":"f","userLast":"Gaartsen","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"f@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"28","userName":"g","userLast":"Klompenboer","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"g@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"29","userName":"h","userLast":"de Jong","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"h@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"30","userName":"i","userLast":"","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"i@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"31","userName":"j","userLast":"","userDegree":"","userOrganization":"","userIndustry":"","userAddressone":"","userAddresstwo":"","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"j@admin.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2d123af96e8de9dcfea549cedbd3ef3e"},{"userID":"60","userName":"Henk","userLast":"Vermeer","userDegree":"dfg","userOrganization":"TRM","userIndustry":"dfg","userAddressone":"Parkdreef 123","userAddresstwo":"Mozartlaan 438","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"fds@fds.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"2dfc96090d0580c77052ea730ca641ec"},{"userID":"61","userName":"dion","userLast":"sdff","userDegree":"sdfsdf","userOrganization":"sdfsd","userIndustry":"h","userAddressone":"fdsgxchvjngfcbvd","userAddresstwo":"nhgjmkhmg","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"7@7.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"a8224f3750dd0fa465f5592b2c8b7691"},{"userID":"62","userName":"asdasdsad","userLast":"asdasdasdsd","userDegree":"asdasdasda","userOrganization":"sdasdasdasd","userIndustry":"asdasdasdas","userAddressone":"dasdasdas","userAddresstwo":"dasdas","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"a@3.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"3158097d42a06f3619a4f65d7332e9ac"},{"userID":"63","userName":"piet","userLast":"molema","userDegree":"sdfmaf","userOrganization":"jnbfkj","userIndustry":"asdasd","userAddressone":"kjb","userAddresstwo":"jb","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"piet@piet.nl","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"8470034e78689fbfdf02a243b2e5791e"},{"userID":"64","userName":"wim","userLast":"piet","userDegree":"sdfnb","userOrganization":"ubhi","userIndustry":"biu","userAddressone":"buikb","userAddresstwo":"iukb","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"qw@qw.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"a4a48ab579a555b02fb73fa35ca19eca"},{"userID":"65","userName":"henk","userLast":"skdfn","userDegree":"kjb","userOrganization":"kj","userIndustry":"nkj","userAddressone":"nkj","userAddresstwo":"n","userCity":"","userState":"","userZip":"","userCountry":"","userPass":"81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055","userPhone":"0","userEmail":"m@m.com","userAssistinfo":"","userStatus":"Y","userCreated":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","tokenCode":"a22bfc97426704ae0894882242a14016"}]
```

The "cols" and "rows" are missing.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Why is the creation of the output separated from the deliver? Where is the call to the json generating script? Where are "cols" and "rows" written as json data?

Comment: I just used this site to make  my php to JSON:  http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/01/convert-mysql-to-json-using-php.html

Comment: Your JSON data does not contain "rows" or "cols". since you haven't provided them.
To solve your problem, write appropriate entries to your JSON file.

Comment: and how do i do that? or do i hve to make a new ticket? because i don't know what to do know. i'm new at this i'm beginning to learn PHP but i really don't know what to do now.

Comment: You're currently collecting data from an SQL query in an array.
Add `$emparray['cols'] = array(1,2,3,); $emparray['rows'] = array(1,2,3);`  before writing it to a file. You should know what data you want to put into "cols" and "rows"

Comment: I did this:   `$emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray['cols'] = array(1,2,3,); $emparray['rows'] = array(1,2,3);
    }



header('Content-Type: application/json');
    //write to json file
    $fp = fopen('users.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($emparray));
    fclose($fp);` i think that is not the correct way.

I really don't know how to output my database instead of the 1,2,3

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't tell you what data to write... you should know what "cols" and "rows" must contain

Comment: Do i have to put my php in it instead of the 1,2,3 or is that not the solution? i really don't know what to do know.

Comment: Seriously? You say "cols and rows are missing" but you don't know what is expected? Then why are you so sure that cols and rows are missing? Do you even know what you want to do?

Comment: yes i want to use google charts and for that i need my php database to be in cols and rows., But i have allot of users registerd and all those users must output in a json file so that google can read this to show it in a line chart or a barchart